# How to use a variable in Swagger_UI commented code style in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, variables, swagger, openapi

I'm using:
openapi: "3.0.0"
Swagger-jsdoc: "^6.2.5",
Swagger-ui-express: "^4.3.0",
Node: v18.8.0

I have an endpoint sending a huge amount of raw_data and I don't want to add such payload in the swagger code. To do so I create a JSON file which I'm parsing and calling it as a variable.

For jest test it worked but for swagger commented code is not working is just recognizing it as a string and not as a variable.

important pieces of my code that could help to understand my problem.

```
const fs = require("fs")
const phonationRaw_data = fs.readFileSync("payloads/    phonationData.json");
const phonationParsedData = JSON.parse(phonationRaw_data);
```

so `phonationParsedData` is my variable containing a big amounts of raw data

```
//! Schema POST
/**
 * @swagger
 * components:
 *   schemas:
 *      Phonation:
 *
 *       type: object
 *
 *       required:
 *         - date
 *         - status
 *         - raw_data
 *
 *       properties:
 *
 *         date:
 *           type: string
 *           timestamp-format: yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
 *           example: "2022-09-21 14:56:15"
 *
 *         status:
 *           type: integer
 *           example: 3
 *
 *         raw_data:
 *           type: string
 *           format: binary                         ↓↓
 *         → example: $ref:phonationParsedData.raw_data   ←  
 */
 //          these line is the one causing problems ↑↑
```

I already tried and I don't know how many more:

- phonationParsedData.raw_data
- `phonationParsedData.raw_data` (here I'm using it to )
- $ref:phonationParsedData.raw_data
- `$ref:phonationParsedData.raw_data`
- ${phonationParsedData.raw_data}
- `${phonationParsedData.raw_data}`

it always logs something similar to these example:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean using a variable in this line --`example: $ref:phonationParsedData.raw_data`?

Comment: Yes. It never recognizing the payload - raw_data is just recognizing it as a string and is showing in swagger  phonationParsedData.raw_data or the others examples i add

Comment: I add an image of the output of swagger in case is not clear